# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel add new row without using index

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to convert a list to an excel file. But I don't think it is going to work by using `WorkSheet.Cells[i, y] = "value"`. I am wondering whether there is a general way to add rows at the end of the last row in Excel.

```
public void AttorneysToExcelFile(List<Scraper.StaggingAttorney> liveScraperAttorneys, string FileName)
{
    Excel.Workbook WorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add();
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)WorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    xlWorkSheet.Name = "No Category";
    liveScraperAttorneys = liveScraperAttorneys.OrderBy(x=>x.Department).ToList();


    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "caseNumber";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Category";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Names";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Email";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Address";

    for (int i=2; i<liveScraperAttorneys.Count; i++)
    {
        Scraper.StaggingAttorney attorney = liveScraperAttorneys[i];

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = attorney.caseNumber;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = attorney.Category;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 3] = attorney.Names;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 4] = attorney.Email;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 5] = attorney.Address;
    }
    WorkBook.SaveAs(FileName);
    WorkBook.Close();
}
```

As you can see I am relying on i. It would help also if I can do it at once. Also I am wondering whether the way I have added headers is the right way to do it.

Comment: This is a little off topic but why are you using Microsoft Excel Interop? Is this for a desktop application?

Comment: Yes. Is there something better? Other packages I have seen are very expensive.

Comment: As someone who's suffered using interoperability libraries, I'd suggest using ClosedXML. It's open source and MIT licensed. Take a look. It is much faster

Answer (score 1):

Iterating Interop objects is brutally slow.  Convert your list to a `object[,]` and then assign it to the Excel `range.Value`.  Add the header row as the first element in the array, then your data as the rest of the elements.  `range` is a range of cells of equal dimensions to your array.  That is, the number of items in your list by the number of properties in your object.

Comment: I have sorted my list using `liveScraperAttorneys = liveScraperAttorneys.OrderBy(x=>x.Department).ToList();` And I want to output the department each time the Department changes. I think your solution assumes that the Cells index will always match with the list index. So Iterating might not work. I am hoping for something like; `xlWorkSheet.AddCell(new string[] {"caseNumber", "Category", "Names", ...})`

Comment: You can still use my suggestion.  Construct the array during your list processing (appending to the end of the array instead of writing to the sheet), then write the array to the worksheet range.  In my experience with the Interop working with an array is BY FAR the most efficient way of doing things.